# Dissolving roads of same levels in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, road

I have a 3D road shape files. Roads are of different levels, highway, primary,secondary and so on. And when i used the tool feature to line i splited every line in every intersection.

Now i want a way to dissolve roads that are snapped at intersection and have the same level (z value). In this way they do not dissolve with other road that pass on the same intersection but on different level (z value).

Like this picture:

[image]

Comment: use definition queries (or select by attribute and export to a fc) so you are only dissolving roads with the same z values.

Comment: The Dissolve tool already deals with this without any other tool.  In the dissolve fields list Select All of the attributes of the line, but uncheck the ObjectID and Length field and any GlobalID (if a line was split the new lines all have identical attributes other than these 3 attributes).  Then use the Single Part option and the Unsplit lines option to only merge lines that touch end to end and retain separate line features if gaps occur between lines.  However, this may remove intersections created by roads that are on the same level. Afterward, select each level and Planarize the roads

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @RichardFairhurst:

> The Dissolve tool already deals with this without any other tool. In
>   the dissolve fields list Select All of the attributes of the line, but
>   uncheck the ObjectID and Length field and any GlobalID (if a line was
>   split the new lines all have identical attributes other than these 3
>   attributes). Then use the Single Part option and the Unsplit lines
>   option to only merge lines that touch end to end and retain separate
>   line features if gaps occur between lines. However, this may remove
>   intersections created by roads that are on the same level. Afterward,
>   select each level and Planarize the roads